# R Shiny XTS - Change name of the default tooltip using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, tooltip, plotly

I have a [xts](/questions/tagged/xts) object that has dates as values, I'm using [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) and [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) app for show the result.
But I want to change the default names of the tooltip when the mouse is on the line.

From:
`index: 2020-03-19
value: 70`

To:
`Date: 2020-03-19
Cantidad: 70`

Code for XTS:

```
data<-rnorm(10)
    dates <- seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), length =10, by = "days")
    xtsMyData <- xts(x = data, order.by = dates)
```

Plot:

```
r <- ggplot(tidy(xtsMyData), aes(x=index,y=value, color=series, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
    ) + geom_line(size=2)
```

The result is:
[image: Default values]

I'm triyng the following code:

```
 r <- ggplot(tidy(xtsMyData), aes(x=index,y=value, color=series, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
    ) + geom_line(size=2)

    return(ggplotly(r, tooltip = **c("x","y", "series" )**) %>% plotly::config(displayModeBar = T)  %>%
             layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.4, y = -0.2)))
```

And the result is:

[image: New result, it's a bit best]

**How can I change the tooltip? Can I add words?** I tried with paste("Dates","x") but doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `text` in `style` to change the hover text.

The `plotly` object will have values accessible through a list as below. The date values will need to be converted with `as.Date`.

**Edit**: The code includes a full shiny app as a demo.

```
library(xts)
library(shiny)

data<-rnorm(10)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), length =10, by = "days")
xtsMyData <- xts(x = data, order.by = dates)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("myplot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myplot <- renderPlotly({
    r <- ggplot(tidy(xtsMyData), aes(x=index,y=value, color=series, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')) + 
      geom_line(size=2)

    r <- ggplotly(r) %>% 
      plotly::config(displayModeBar = T) %>%
      layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.4, y = -0.2)) 

    r %>%
      style(text = paste0("Date:", as.Date(r$x$data[[1]]$x), 
                          "</br></br>", 
                          "Cantidad:", r$x$data[[1]]$y))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Plot**

[image: plotly plot with hover text modified]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I understan your idea, but I have an error: "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'". The content of the variable "text" is:  <br><br> [1] "Date:2020-01-22" "Date:2020-01-23" "Date:2020-01-24" "Date:2020-01-25"
 [5] "Date:2020-01-26" "Date:2020-01-27" "Date:2020-01-28" "Date:2020-01-29"
 [9] "Date:2020-01-30" "Date:2020-01-31" "Date:2020-02-01" "Date:2020-02-02"

Comment: @ErickPineda See edited answer for full shiny example. Are you able to reproduce this? To look further into your error, can you edit your question with your shiny code (enough to reproduce), and perhaps sample of data using `dput()`?

Answer (score 0):

The first answer gave me the idea to change manually all, because I had 2 different geom_lines and that didn't work for me , this labels are stored in `r$x$data[[1]]$text` (the following line plots are in `r$x$data[[2]]$text,r$x$data[[3]]$text`... ), so, if you use an gsub, you could change everything you want, it's very dumb but it works. (You can use the same philosophy to delete the last label, manipulating strings)

I put an example for your problem, despite you already solve it, other person could have more than one line plot.

```
r$x$data[[1]]$text<-gsub(r$x$data[[1]]$text,pattern='index', replacement='Fecha')

r$x$data[[1]]$text<-gsub(r$x$data[[1]]$text,pattern='value', replacement='Valor')

r$x$data[[1]]$text<-gsub(r$x$data[[1]]$text,pattern='series', replacement='Serie')
```